# Weird UInt64 behavior in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I've been playing around with a BigInteger implementation, and I found something strange...

This bit of code:

```
let largeInt: UInt64 = UInt64(pow(Double(2), Double(64)))
```

I expected it to crash.. but instead largeInt is equal to 0. After that, if I try to use largeInt, I get unexpected results.

For example, this:

```
let int1: UInt64 = largeInt - 1
```

Once again, I expected it to crash (0 - 1 is obviously not a valid unsigned int). However, in the debugger it doesn't crash, and I see a a value of 3472 (??). Any ideas as to what's going on?

EDIT:
Actually it looks like the second line does cause a crash, but not until the end of the function (I had a breakpoint on the line after I set int1). largeInt still doesn't cause a crash though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug to me.

```
let p1 = pow(Double(2), Double(64))
```

is greater than `UInt64.max`, therefore

```
let x1 = UInt64(p1)
```

should crash (or perhaps return `UInt64.max` as an approximation).

The "next smaller" floating point double variable

```
let p2 = nextafter(p1, 0.0)
let x2 = UInt64(p2)
// 18446744073709549568
```

is converted correctly, and the "next larger" floating point double variable
fails correctly to convert

```
let p3 = nextafter(p1, DBL_MAX)
let x3 = UInt64(p3)
// fatal error: floating point value can not be converted to UInt64
// because it is greater than UInt64.max
```

Comment: This does feel like a bug. `let largeInt: UInt64 = UInt64(pow(Double(2), Double(64)) + 100)` is also 0. Makes me suspect that they have a > where they should have a >=. But `let largeInt: UInt64 = UInt64(pow(Double(2), Double(65))` does crash.

Comment: @RobNapier: `UInt64(pow(Double(2), Double(64)) + 100)` is also zero because `pow(Double(2), Double(64)) + 100` is equal to `pow(Double(2), Double(64))` as a `Double`. With the next larger number which is representable as a `Double`, the conversion to UInt64 crashes.